# Huge compilation time when linking with library using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, qmake, boost-serialization

Hello and thanks for reading.

I have a dynamic library using boost::serialization with about 200 different classes. I use this library in my program, thanks to the header messageExports.h, which looks like this :

```
#include "classe1.h"
//...
#include "classe200.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(ns::classe1);
//...
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(ns::classe200);
```

But the file including messaeExports.h needs a really long time to compile, and this each time I modify it. As I am using Qt and qmake, i tried the PRECOMPILED_HEADERS method but it took a lot more time than without, and it seems qmake adds the precompiled header to each obj file.

Do you have idea how I could reduce my compilation time ? Is it possible to rearrange the messageExport.h header to avoid the boost export defines ?

Thank you in advance,

Roland

Comment: We have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I assume the header contains the typical templated `serialize` functions as well? If so, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027103/boostserialization-is-it-possible-to-avoid-template-functions) may help.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing sample code would probably help, but...

Can you remove common, boilerplate code from "classe*.h" easily?

Use include guards to prevent multiple includes of the same file?

```
// File: ---classe1.h---
#ifndef __CLASSE1_H_INCLUDED
#define __CLASSE1_H_INCLUDED
// Stuff goes here
// Here
// Here (ad naseum)
#endif // __CLASSE1_H_INCLUDED
// End Of File: ---classe1.h---
```

Just a few suggestions...

Comment: double underscores are not allowed.

Comment: I already use include guards and I have common base class for all the classx files to avoid common code. Thanks